# ARRAYFORMULA but only untill EMPTY cells in row - doesn't work

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, count-unique

I'm trying to copy from one tab to another with `ARRAYFORMULA`.

It works. but it does copy all empty cells in a row too. I don't want that.

Here is my code:

```
={"Elevplan - Prosa (" & TÆLV('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C) & "/" & COUNTUNIQUE('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C) & " elever)" ;
ARRAYFORMULA(
HVIS(ER.TOM('Formularsvar 1'!C2:(TÆLV('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C))); "Tom: ";

(

'Formularsvar 1'!C2:C & char(10) &
'Formularsvar 1'!D1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$D$2:D&" "&
'Formularsvar 1'!E1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$E$2:E&" "&
'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G& char(10)

)


)
 ) 
}
```

It takes all cells in row C from tab 'Formularsvar 1' but the 10 last cells are empty.

How can I set a limit like C2:C22 when C is dynamic?

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vH4bXphjdxRJzHveb4R5Ssx9F6EkT_ishZ-LQhKsMAs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={"Elevplan - Prosa ("&COUNTA('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C)&"/"&
 COUNTUNIQUE('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C)&" elever)";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C),
 ('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!D1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$D$2:D&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!E1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$E$2:E&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&CHAR(10)), "Tom: "))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It is working - almost. It doesn't say "Tom or Empty" and somehow the output-tab; Til kopering produces an extra 500 rows.

Comment: try: `={"Elevplan - Prosa ("&COUNTA('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C)&"/"&
 COUNTUNIQUE('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C)&" elever)";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C),
 ('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!D1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$D$2:D&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!E1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$E$2:E&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&CHAR(10)), "Tom: "))}`

Comment: Works perfect! Still another 500 rows though.

Comment: Things kinda grew... I can add a new question if I'm supposed to? The question is; Is it possible to ad an Select... Where Column Klasse i i.e. 7L and group it on another tab?

Comment: like this? `={"Elevplan - Prosa ("&COUNTA('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D)&"/"&
 COUNTUNIQUE('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D)&" elever)";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D))*('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C="7L"),
 ('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!E1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$E$2:E&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!G1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!$H$2:H&CHAR(10)), ))}`

Comment: Yes. And no. Jobs done but result is spread all over sheet. Is it possible to show them ordered?

Comment: like this? `={"Elevplan - Prosa ("&COUNTA('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D)&"/"&
 COUNTUNIQUE('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D)&" elever)";
 QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D))*('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C="7L"),
 ('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!E1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$E$2:E&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!G1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!$H$2:H&CHAR(10)), )),"where Col1 is not null", 0)}`

Comment: Can I get you some coffee? The empty rows are still showing - any way to get rid of them?